# GET with body (json format), what to do with apostrophe?

Tags: rest

I am new to REST. I have a client who tries call an api I have running. Problem is that they use some type of builder to create the body.

In my endpoint, I expect `name` field in the body like this:

```
{
"name": [
{ "tag": "1", "value": "O'Bryan" },
...
```

But client sends something like this:

```
{
'name': [
{'tag': '1 ', 'value': 'O'Bryan'}
```

It works except when name has ***apostrophe***. I am wondering if this body will still valid. If not, what can they do to fix it without using double quote(")?

Comment: when they generate json, values need to be escaped, so it should be something like 'value': 'O\'Bryan'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This body will not be valid, you would need to escape the single quote like so `\'`

Comment: I see. Just quick question.. If name doesn't have apostrophe, it should work right? Also, can I use double quote (") instead of single quote for `name`, `tag`, and `value` and not use escape?

Comment: If everything is double quotes then it will work, but your O'bryan messes up the JSON format if you use single quotes